# Google Admin SDK error Resource Not Found: domain when trying to list existing users

Tags: python, google-apps, google-directory-api

I am trying to write a simple script to get a list of my Google Apps users using Google's python API. So far it looks like this (based on a Google example):

```
!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2

from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

client_email = 'service_account_email@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
with open("Python GAPS-98dfb88b4c9f.p12") as f:
  private_key = f.read()

OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, OAUTH_SCOPE )
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

directory_service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)

all_users = []
page_token = None
params = {'customer': 'my_customer'}

while True:
  try:
    if page_token:
      param['pageToken'] = page_token
    current_page = directory_service.users().list(**params).execute()

    all_users.extend(current_page['users'])
    page_token = current_page.get('nextPageToken')
    if not page_token:
      break
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
    break

for user in all_users:
  print user['primaryEmail']
```

The service account has been authorized on google developer console for the following API's:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias

However, when I run the code, I get this error:

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&alt=json returned "Resource Not Found: domain">
```

Any hints on what am I missing?

E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even when using a service account, you still need to "act as" a Google Apps user in the domain with the proper rights (e.g. a super admin). Try:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key,
                        OAUTH_SCOPE, sub='admin@domain.com')
```

where admin@domain.com is the email of a super admin in your domain.